debuging a ms access project
From a previous, curently gone missing dev I inherited a MS Access database (project?). The problem is, while changes are made in one of the form, a broken sql query is executed. I was looking in several fields and subforms for onchange, onupdate, onlostforcus actions etc - nothing. I was trying to debug the "project" with breakpoints in the vba code to go step-by-step all the actions performed, but it looks like the debuging/F8/step-by-step works only inside a particular procedure.
Is there any way to force the VBA/access to perform a real step-by-step debugging? I'm trying to find a way to force the app to stop at every action perform to be able where and what code (event?) is executed.
And yes, sadly it's a MsAccess2007 project.

It can be tricky to identify the issue. I suggest posting a job on a freelance site like Upwork to connect with a professional via video call or remote access through an app like TeamViewer.

Issue may not be VBA code, and hence no debugger will be available or help you. Most of Access form's don't require VBA code and hence debug of code will not help you. That query could be a text box with a expression that does a dcount(), dsum(), dmax(), dlookup() etc. can trigger the query. Such expressions don't use VBA and thus trying to step though VBA code not going to help. Forms are a VERY complex objects and can trigger + run queries without VBA code, hence you have to look at the control's data source setting. Queries can run in a form without VBA,  so some debug of VBA will not help

So control sources such as one for a combo box, or a list box also have a query (data) source, and I would look at those first - that's most likely what is triggering the query. If no combo box, or list box, then as noted in above comments, then you have to start looking at the control source(s) on that form - so, first check the combo boxes sources - as noted, they don't require VBA, so stepping though VBA is of no use here.

A volunteer service like UtterAccess may be able to help you.
